# SQL Server 2005 service broker stopped calling procedure

Tags: sql-server-2005, service-broker

I have a service broker (`retention = OFF` ) which calls a stored procedure `SP_dequeue`.

```
--Register SP for Dequeue operation
ALTER QUEUE [TEST_Queue] WITH RETENTION = OFF,ACTIVATION 
(      STATUS = ON,      
MAX_QUEUE_READERS = 1,      
PROCEDURE_NAME = sp_dequeue,      
EXECUTE AS owner
);
```

`TRUSTWORTHY` and broker is enabled

`SP_dequeue` basically does a

```
RECEIVE TOP(1) from the TEST_Queue
```

and processes the data. It was running fine for months, but suddenly the service broker has stopped calling the procedure `SP_dequeue`. But when I select the queue I can see a lot of rows with `STATUS = 1` and `sys.transmission_queue` is empty.

What all can be the reason ??? When I check the event log there is no error or message. In between machine was restarted. After restarting also the queue was working fine up to 2 weeks. Kindly help..

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM queue` or `RECEIVE ... from queue`? An activated procedure **MUST** call RECEIVE.

Comment: What is the meaning of Execute as Owner? Doc says "Specifies that the stored procedure executes as the owner of the queue" On an insert trigger i am doing an enqueue operation.

Comment: Problem got solved when i restarted the machine.. There was a lot of insufficient memeory isuue.. Still no idea y the queue was not calling SP...

Comment: I was not able to ask question.But after upvote i can ask question Thanks for upvote.Thanks a lot... I really missed stackoverflow Thanks again